# How to add Map to Android Master/Detail Flow properly?

Tags: android, dictionary

in Android SDK I've created an app with the Master/Detail Flow template and now I'd like to add a Google MapView from the Palette to the activity_item_detail.xml as follows:

[attempt to insert Map into Master/Detail Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOsBs.png)

The project compiles, however when I launch the app in the simulator and choose an item on the item list, the app in the simulator crashes. I'm not sure on how to fix this. What are the steps I have to do? Where do I have to add additional code? Same thing happens by the way if I merely add a button to the item_detail_container. Your help is greatly appreciated!

activity_item_detail.xml is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.ralfmatz.testapplication.ItemDetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/item_detail_container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please show some code as well

Comment: Upon creation on the project I haven't added additional code, just dropped the Map (or Button) from the Palette to the activity_item_detail.xml pane.

Answer (score 0):

since you haven't shown any logcat output, I assume
you have to add Google Map API in order to view the maps and avoid crashes

See the maps api reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I've modified the project and now I works. But the map is on a different activity. I'll keep you posted.